# jquery Doing Simple Math?

Tags: jquery

I have a little DIV like this:

```
<div id="counter">2</div>
```

I'd like to use jQUery to either subtract or add by let say 1, resulting in 3 or 1...

is there a way in jquery to do this? convert a string to a int maybe?

Comment: Also, how to add a floor of 0 ? I don't want negative numbers showing up! :)

Comment: use Math.max(yournumber,0) to ensure that there will be no negative numbers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$('#counter').text(function(i,txt) { return parseInt(txt, 10) + 1; });
```

**Example for addition:** http://jsfiddle.net/2uBMy/

**Example for subtraction:** http://jsfiddle.net/2uBMy/1/

To add a check for negative, you could do this:

```
$('#counter').text(function(i,txt) {
    var result = parseInt(txt, 10) - 1;
    return (result > 0) ? result : 0; 
});
```

Comment: It parses the contents of txt in base 10

Comment: @AnApprentice - The `txt` represents the current text value of `#coutner`, and the `10` ensures the value is parsed as a base 10 number. If there's a leading `0`, it will be parsed as an octal.

Comment: Something wrong, that works for up 1 down one, but if the count is 3, and I go to subtract 1 ,it goes down to 0

Comment: @AnApprentice - I'd have to see your code. There's something wrong if so.

Answer (score 8):

```
$('#counter').text(function(i, txt) {
    return +txt + 1;
});
```

That way, the content from `#counter` are converted into an integer. This works great for numbers, but if for some reason something like "foo123" is the content, it would become `NaN`.

So another way to parse it is to use `.parseInt()`

```
$('#counter').text(function(i, txt) {
    return parseInt(txt, 10) + 1;
});
```

`parseInt()` expects two arguments, a value and a radix (base number). If this is invoked on "foo123" it will return "123". One could say that this is a wrong behavior, so you need to decide which variant you want to have.

Example: http://www.jsfiddle.net/Mtvju/

Ref.: [.text()](http://api.jquery.com/textl/)

Comment: +1 Wow, didn't know a callback is possible. Is it with `.html()`, too?

Comment: @generalhenry - He's doing `+txt` which converts the string to a number.

Comment: @AndreKR: yes `.html()` along with a few other methods do parse the textual contents into a callback since jQuery 1.4.0

Comment: @generalhenry: `+` is like an implicit cast. If it's not possible to cast the value into a number it will return `NaN`, see the example link.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#counter').html(  +($('#counter').html()) + 1 );
```

Comment: This would result in `"11"`, from `"1" + 1`.  Because string + int coerces the int into a string, then concatenates it.

Answer (score 1):

```
var counter = $('#counter');
var value   = parseInt(counter.html());
counter.html(value + 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, convert it to an `int`. Use [parseInt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) to convert it to an integer. Then use jQuery's [.html](http://api.jquery.com/html/) to get the contents of the `<div>` and to replace those contents with the new value.

```
$("#counter").html(parseInt($("#counter").html(),10) + 1)
$("#counter").html(parseInt($("#counter").html(),10) - 1)
```

[Try it here!](http://jsfiddle.net/ypvCj/)

Answer (score 0):

javascript is loosely typed.  You can use strings that contain numbers and numbers as if they where both for most purposes.   The one place to be careful is the `+`, which is both add and concatenate.  You need to disambiguate somehow.

```
function subtract()
{
   count = $('#counter').html();
   if(count > 0)
   {
     count--;
   }
   $('#counter').html(count)
}
```